# Diploma Withheld

Tags: application

I will graduate from a university with a BA and two AA degrees at the end of April 2018. I intend to go to another university and get an accelerated BSN degree. Part of the requirement for admission into the accelerated BSN degree program is that I show that I graduated from a university with a BA and a cumulative GPA of at least 3.0, which I will certainly have. However, I will have an overdue balance of $8000 that I owe this university, which may or may not be paid by the time I intend to begin my accelerated BSN (June 2019, roughly a year from now).

Does anyone know if universities have a way of cross-checking with another university that I graduated if I can't supply them with a transcript or diploma because it's being withheld? I've emailed the university asking about it and, until they respond, I wanted to see if anyone here had some information or knowledge.

Comment: The leverage the university has to make sure you pay comes from refusing to formally authenticate your degree to third parties, not from quibbling over the difference between transcript, diploma, and some hypothetical cross-check.  So even if there is an alternative to the transcript, that alternative is also going to be on hold due to the outstanding debt.

Comment: Did you ask if an official transcript is required showing the degree having been awarded?  Did you ask your current school whether the official and/or unofficial transcripts will say that the degree was awarded?  Maybe your current school has some policy about this on their website?  Can you get them to document your degree by agreeing to a payment plan?

Answer (score 4):

In the U.S., at least, your new university would insist on seeing a final, official transcript... but your old university would very likely *not* send one until all debts are paid to them.

If money is a serious issue here, you should talk to your "old" university and arrange a payment plan... and then they may be more willing to release your records. In the U.S., if you try to dodge this, it will eventually catch up with you, and you would most likely not be allowed to register at the new place (until they get official documents from the old place).

Comment: Hi, @paul garrett. I certainly intend to pay back what I owe; I’m not trying to avoid that. I’m simply trying to get a second degree that would enable me to get a certain job that would allow me to pay them back easily and quickly.

Comment: Then (thinking of the U.S. context) you need to negotiate directly, rather than delay talking to people. That is, even if you yourself plan without doubt to pay those debts, other people will not know this until you tell them, and a mere vague promise "eventual repayment" may not get you the transcript needed to register at the new place.